# FragmentStateAdapter for ViewPager2 notifyItemChanged not working as expected

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I am using ViewPager2 with FragmentStateAdapter and i am calling notifyItemChanged(position). But as expected createFragment method not calling again. Is it is the intended behavior or bug, what should I do

My Code is

```
    class EEditionPagerAdapter(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle, private var date: String
    ) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {

    private var menuList = emptyList<EEditionMenu>()

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = menuList.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        val menu = menuList[position]
        return EEditionListingFragment.newInstance(menu, date)
    }

    fun submitList(list: List<EEditionMenu>) {
        menuList = list
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, menuList.size)
    }

    fun changeDate(date: String, position: Int){
        this.date = date
        notifyItemChanged(position)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call notifyItemChanged for FragmentStateAdapter it call `ensureFragment(position)`that restores the fragment if it has already been created

```
 private void ensureFragment(int position) {
    long itemId = getItemId(position);
    if (!mFragments.containsKey(itemId)) {
        // TODO(133419201): check if a Fragment provided here is a new Fragment
        Fragment newFragment = createFragment(position);
        newFragment.setInitialSavedState(mSavedStates.get(itemId));
        mFragments.put(itemId, newFragment);
    }
}
```

Try to override onBindViewHolder and set Date to fragment

```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(
    holder: FragmentViewHolder,
    position: Int,
    payloads: MutableList<Any>
) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)
    val fragment: EEditionListingFragment? = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("f$position") as EEditionListingFragment?
    fragment.updateDate(date)
}
```

Comment: So what should I do to refresh the current page fragment

Comment: Сompleted the answer

Comment: Nice - odd though that there is no get method for this if the truly want to bridge the gap between viewpager and recyclerview...

Comment: @slott The bridge is using your own item IDs

Answer (score 7):

FragmentStateAdapter uses item IDs to determine if a fragment has already been created and reuses already created ones. By default, an item ID is the item's position. You can override `getItemId` and `containsItem` to provide your own unique IDs based on positions and dates, then it will ask for a new fragment when the date changes.

Answer (score 0):

The fragment put to the mFragment in FragementStateAdapter.class is managed by the

```
void placeFragmentInViewHolder(@NonNull final FragmentViewHolder holder)
```

method, which is package private and we do not have access and in this method the fragment is added to the mFragment manager with tag `"f" + holder.getItemId()` which is the same as `"f" + position`.

```
        scheduleViewAttach(fragment, container);
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(fragment, "f" + holder.getItemId())
                .setMaxLifecycle(fragment, STARTED)
                .commitNow();
        mFragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer.updateFragmentMaxLifecycle(false);
```

For this reason, we can override the `onBindViewHolder` method while a fragement shall be displayed.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FragmentViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);
    if (position == 0) {

        String fragmentTag = "f" + holder.getItemId();
        Log.v(TAG,"fragmentTag is : " + fragmentTag);
        MyFragment fragment0 = (MyFragment) this.mFragmentManger.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);

        if (fragment0 != null) {
            Log.v(TAG,"onBindViewHolder updating fragment ...");
            // do what ever you want to update the MyFragment 
            fragment0.update(payloads);
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG,"onBindViewHolder called, but fragment0 is null!");
        }
    }
}
```

In my case the `this.mFragmentManager` is cashed through the constructor.

```
public MyFragmentStateAdapter(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        super(fragment); // this calls the fragment.getChildFragmentManager().
        this.mFragmentManger = fragment.getChildFragmentManager();
}
```

And the `createFragment()` is:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
    if(position == 0){
        if (this.fragment0 == null) {
            this.fragment0 = MyFragment.getInstance();
        }
        return this.fragment0;
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "position " + position + " is called");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Finally, call the update in somewhere else to trigger the update:

```
ViewPager2.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(0, null); 
// 0 is the fragment position of the fragment0 and null is payload.
```