# NotifyDataSetChanged not working in FragmentStateAdapter with Viewpager2

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstateadapter

I am making a file selection page with viewpager2 with FragmentStateAdapter. In one of the pages I show all mounted storage devices on which I would like to tap to view the contents but I want the contents to be on another fragment.

I want to replace fragment with another one in the last page of viewpager. but with the following code, the page just refreshes and new Fragment is not created as `createFragment` does not get called.

My PagerAdapter

```
public static class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {


        private Fragment mFragmentAtPos0;
        private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
        private final FirstPageListener listener = new FirstPageListener();
        public final class FirstPageListener implements
                FirstPageFragmentListener {
            public void onSwitchToNextFragment() {
                mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mFragmentAtPos0)
                        .commit();
                if (mFragmentAtPos0 instanceof FilesandFolder_Others_MainPage){
                    mFragmentAtPos0 = new FileExplorer(listener);
                }else{ // Instance of NextFragment
                    mFragmentAtPos0 = new FilesandFolder_Others_MainPage(listener);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            public void onSwitchToNextFragment(Bundle bundle) {
//                mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mFragmentAtPos0)
//                        .commit();
                if (mFragmentAtPos0 instanceof FilesandFolder_Others_MainPage){
                    mFragmentAtPos0 = new FileExplorer(listener);
                    mFragmentAtPos0.setArguments(bundle);
                }else{ // Instance of NextFragment
                    mFragmentAtPos0 = new FilesandFolder_Others_MainPage(listener);
                    mFragmentAtPos0.setArguments(bundle);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
//                notifyItemChanged(getItemPosition(mFragmentAtPos0));
            }
        }


//        @Override
//        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FragmentViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {
//            super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);
//            if (position == getItemPosition(mFragmentAtPos0)) {
//
//                Fragment f = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("f" + holder.getItemId());
//                if (f != null) {
//                    mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(holder.getItemId(), )
//                }
//            }
//        }

        private int getItemPosition(Fragment mFragmentAtPos0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++){

                if (createFragment(i).equals(mFragmentAtPos0)){
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }


        public PagerAdapter(FragmentActivity fm) {
            super(fm);
            mFragmentManager = fm.getSupportFragmentManager();
            mFragmentAtPos0 = new FilesandFolder_Others_MainPage(listener);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new AppSelectionFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new Photos();
                case 2:
                    return new VideoGalleryFragment();
                case 3:
                    return new Gallery();
                default:
                    return mFragmentAtPos0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 5;
        }
    }
```

Here is the constructor of Fragment from which I would like to replace to another Fragment:

```
    private static FileSelection.PagerAdapter.FirstPageListener pageFragmentListener;

    public FilesandFolder_Others_MainPage() {
    }
    public FilesandFolder_Others_MainPage(FileSelection.PagerAdapter.FirstPageListener firstPageFragmentListener) {
        pageFragmentListener = firstPageFragmentListener;
    }
```

And on tap of a view,
the following code is supposed to be called:-

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("PATH", volumes.get(position).path);
pageFragmentListener.onSwitchToNextFragment(bundle);
```

I have searched all over stackoverflow, and never saw a proper answer with viewpager 2 and FragmentStateAdapter as everyone seems to be using Viewpager

I tried to implement this:- [FragmentStateAdapter for ViewPager2 notifyItemChanged not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60408236/fragmentstateadapter-for-viewpager2-notifyitemchanged-not-working-as-expected)

but couldn't understand how to edit my code. Pls help
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm trying to do the same. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 7):

Had same problem, and that's what i found:

`FragmentStateAdapter` has method `onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)`, which you can override (unlike `onBindViewHolder(holder, position)` which is final). This method calls when you call `notify` methods, and for `notifyItemChanged()`, `notifyItemRangeChanged()` methods you can access the fragment, and manually update it.

Here is code to access the fragment:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FragmentViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {

    String tag = "f" + holder.getItemId();

    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);

    if (fragment != null) {
        //manual update fragment
    } else {
        // fragment might be null, if it`s call of notifyDatasetChanged() 
        // which is updates whole list, not specific fragment
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);
    }
}
```

`FragmentStateAdapter` is tagged his fragments by `"f" + holder.getItemId()`, that's why it works.

Also you can use `DiffUtil`, and this is better way. [Here is good example](https://proandroiddev.com/viewpager2-and-diffutil-d853cdab5f4a) of solving this problem, and some links in the end for better understanding of `ViewPager2`.

Comment: It's nice to know this `onBindViewHolder(...)` method exists and can be overridden like this to update the Fragments in a `ViewPager2`. Anyone using this approach has to take into account that it's relying on an implementation detail of `FragmentStateAdapter`, i.e. the fact that Fragments are being added to the `FragmentManager` with the tag `"f" + holder.getItemId()`. You should cover your application with some UI tests so that you detect at development time if this implementation detail is ever changed in future versions of the `FragmentStateAdapter` class.

Comment: Yes, that's not safe. Maybe if compare fragments tags manually instead of using `fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("f" + holder.getItemId())` will made is safe.

Comment: In my case I have a FragmentActivity instead, do you know how I could still make this work?

Answer (score 4):

you can override this two method

```
    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        // generate new id
        return getItem(position).hashCode().toLong()
    }

    override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean {
        // false if item is changed
        return dataList.find { it.hashCode().toLong() == itemId } != null
    }
```

Comment: This cause `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Design assumption violated.` when screen is recreated.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue today and thought I would share my solution here. Instead of intercepting `onBindViewHolder()`, my solution simply replaces the old fragment:

```
OldFragment.instance.containerId?.let {
    replace(it, NewFragment.instance)
}
```

To be more concrete:

My App has a ViewPager2 with two fragments. Let's call them `MainFragment` and `DetailFragment`. On a button click in the `MainFragment`, I wanted to replace it with a `SecondMainFragment`. And the same behaviour vice versa: Button click in `SecondMainFragment` would replace itself with the `MainFragment`.

```
class CustomFragmentStateAdapter(
    private val fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {

    var displaySecondMainFragment: Boolean = false
        set(value) {
            if (field != value) {
                switchFragments(replaceWithSecondMainFragment = value)
            }
            field = value
        }

    private fun switchFragments(replaceWithSecondMainFragment: Boolean) {
        fragmentActivity.supportFragmentManager.commit {
            if (replaceWithSecondMainFragment) {
                MainFragment.instance.containerId?.let {
                    replace(it, SecondMainFragment.instance)
                }
            } else {
                SecondMainFragment.instance.containerId?.let {
                    replace(it, MainFragment.instance)
                }
            }
        }
    }
        
    // Standard adapter overrides
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = 2

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment = when (position) {
        0 -> if (displaySecondMainFragment) SecondMainFragment.instance else MainFragment.instance
        else -> DetailFragment.instance
    } 
}
```

With this extension property to get the id of the container the fragment is in:

```
inline val Fragment.containerId: Int?
    get() = (view?.parent as? ViewGroup?)?.id
```

In the end I would only need to do something like that:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    customFragmentStateAdapter.displaySecondMainFragment = true // Or false for the other way
}
```